# Java Homework using inheritence

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jwindow

I'm working on homework that asks me to research the java api for which class is inherited by the JFrame class that declares the setVisible method. Then, import that class and modify the code in the main method so the frame variable is declared as that type rather than the JFrame type.

I've found what class declares the setVisible method, JWindow, but anytime I try to change the code it won't run so any help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JWindow;


//JFrame is inherited from java.awt.Frame class
//setVisible is declared by the java.awt.Window class
public class ProductFrame extends JWindow
{
    public ProductFrame()
    {
        // all of these methods are available because
        // they are inherited from the JFrame class
        // and its superclasses

        this.setTitle("Product");
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setLocation(10, 10);
        this.setResizable(false);

        // this method uses a field that's available
        // because it's inherited
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // this creates an instance of the ProductFrame
        JWindow frame = new ProductFrame();

        // this displays the frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is very vague and unclear to me. may be just me?!!!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be vague. Maybe the textbook I got it from is vague lol I'm trying to change extends JFrame to JWindow and still have the code run normally.

Comment: If you have a look at the JavaDocs for [`JWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) you will find that` setDefaultCloseOperation` is not decalred within it.  It's declared by `JFrame` directly

Comment: Yes, I seen that. I don't know how I'm supposed to modify the code and still be able to run normally. Is there a similar method in the JWindow class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found some class that has a method "setVisible()".
However, your task was to find a class that JFrame inherits from.

JFrame does not inherit from JWindow.

In other words:
If you had the task to find an **ancestor** of yours and interview them about their job, interviewing your sister or cousin will not get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Since your class `ProductFrame` extends `JFrame` directly, you cannot say

```
JWindow frame = new ProductFrame();
```

It's not valid to set a `JWindow` reference equal to a `ProductFrame` because `ProductFrame` does not extend `JWindow`.  You need to change the class declaration so that it does.